# Ошибка выполнения кода, хочу вытянуть из таблицы количество колонок и строк, но что то не дает

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\webdriver firefox\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('file:///C:/Users/eeNNdd11/Desktop/selenium/dsds.html')
rows = len(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr'))
print(rows)
```

А вот собственно и ошибка:

```
ws = len(driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr'))
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Ссылка на таблицу прилагаю: https://yadi.sk/d/3DavlHuT7FVdhw

Answer (score 0):

Зачем Вам Селениум? Это обычная html-таблица, ее можно запарсить через BeatifulSoup. Селениум нужен для работы с интерактивными объектами (например, таблица, требующая прокрутки или кликов). 
Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь посчитать длину функции.

Обратите внимание, что в структуре сайта у заголовка таблицы и обычных строк разные тэги: `th` и `td` соответственно. Ниже -- пример реализации вашей задачи с BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

# открытие локального файла через open()
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("YOUR_PATH_TO/Таблица.html"), "html.parser")) 

table = soup.find('table')
rows = []

for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
    rows.append(tr.find_all(['th', 'td']))

print('Number of rows: ', len(rows), '\t', 'Number of columns: ', len(rows[0]))
```